# Two inline TextFormField wrong spaces on Validation Error

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I created a form in where I have two TextFormFields side by side, the issue is that when the validation error message displays, one of the TextFormField is going up, letting the other one a bit down. How can I do to correct this little design error

#### Here is the screenshot of what I am getting

[image]

#### Here is the way I designed it

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => utils.selectDate(context, _dateCtrl),
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          child: TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            controller: _dateCtrl,
            validator: (value) => Validate.getMsg('date', value),
            decoration: buildInputDecoration(
              false,
              'Date',
              iconData: Icons.calendar_today,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 5),
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => utils.selectTime(context, _timeCtrl),
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          child: TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            controller: _timeCtrl,
            validator: (value) => Validate.getDateTimeMsg(
              'time',
              value,
            ),
            decoration: buildInputDecoration(
              false,
              'Time',
              iconData: Icons.access_time,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

#### Here is the code for the buildInputDecoration Method

```
InputDecoration buildInputDecoration(bool isTextArea, String hintText,
          {IconData iconData}) =>
      InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: isTextArea ? EdgeInsets.all(15.0) : null,
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        hintText: hintText,
        prefixIcon: isTextArea ? null : Icon(iconData),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
      );
```

Comment: We can't sort this issue without you sharing your `buildInputDecoration` method. Building your code without it results in normal side by side TextFormFields. So either the issue is in the decoration coming out of that method, or somewhere else in the code that you haven't shared.

Comment: Okay @JoãoSoares let me edit my post with the buildInputDecoration

Comment: I just realized that when the `errorText` for the `time` field displays, a space is created below it, causing the date field to stay down because no space exists for it. The two inline textformfield work well when the `errorText` displays for both time and date.

I basically need a solution to create the down space in both fields when one has `errorText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is add the `CrossAxisAlignment` to your row to be at the top:

```
...

child: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[

...
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below property in Row Wiget

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```